# How can I only load one function from an extension?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions

In PostgreSQL, I am loading the `uuid-ossp` extension so I can use the function that creates random UUIDs in my queries:

```sql
create extension if not exists "uuid-ossp";
```

However, as well as making available the one function I need (`uuid_generate_v4`), it also makes nine other functions that I don't need available:

[image: The functions available in my postgresql gui]

(Using `\df` on the command-line shows the same data). Is there any way I can, using programming terms, "import" just the `uuid_generate_v4` function into my "namespace", without importing the ones I'm not using?

Comment: You can't. An extension is a single unit (btw: `gen_random_uuid()` from [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html) is **a lot** faster than uuid_generate_v4)

Comment: You can easily write your own function: see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21327318) or [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29147935)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did expect the answer was going to be "you can't, but here's the closest way".

Comment: Out of curiosity, what problem are you having with the other functions? If they're not being called, they're not going to use any online resources.

Comment: You can install extensions into a different schema, to take some of the clutter out of your default schema.  You can either do one schema per extension, or just make one schema for all extensions you use.

Comment: I don't *need* them gone, I just want them gone because I'm not using them! Same reason I only import the functions/classes I'm using in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL 13, the [`gen_random_uuid()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-uuid.html) function is now available globally, with no need to use the pgcrypto or uuid-ossp extensions.

**It is still not possible to only load one function from an extension**, but for this common case, it's possible to generate random UUIDs without having all those other UUID-related functions in scope.